# git rebase - why multiple diffs need to be resolved

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have used git rebase a few times and I am still confused about how it actually works.

With git-merge it seems simple - resolve the diff between the tip of your branch and the tip of the other branch.

However with git-rebase often times we are resolving multiple diffs when doing the rebase. I believe the number of resolved diffs is "how many commits my branch has that the other branch doesnt have" is that correct? but still why do need to resolve all the diffs, why not just the diff for the most recent commit on my branch?

alternatively, doing git-rebase could mean resolving all the diffs for "all the commits from the other branch that my branch doesnt have"! i havent figured out which is which. Can anyone explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

A rebase is a request to move a series of *patches* from one place in your commit hierarchy to another place in your hierarchy. It is just like a series of 'cherry-pick's (yes, it really is ;-)

So first you need to identify the correct list of commits, treated as patches, that you want to move. Beware of misunderstandings about some of the revision range options (some do not work. They don't even say what you thought). Beware of your "Upstream" - it may not be what you think, so Git may think the patch has already been applied to the "upstream".

Having got your series of patches (range of commits), those patches need to be applied, one by one, to the new destination. You are doing this because it is a better place and usually already has some fixes already applied.

The first patch (diff) is applied, there was some minor conflict, say the new ('upstream') place had renamed a variable, while you edited the formula. It will be a conflict (two changes to the same place, or adjacent lines). So you fix the first patch conflicts.

Now the second patch hits the same awkward spot. Its a dumb diff. It knows not enough of the rename and line fixes and so can't find the right exact starting point, so you have to resolve it again. Cue third patch, and the same style of problem recurs.

This is especially bad if your commits are not atomic (i.e. each really small!). and without the semantic (renames etc) changes.

So, rebase quite often if you have a fast moving upstream (i.e. keep up), or do it very occasionally (i.e. do one big fix-it session).

Also, use the "ReReRe" facility. This is the 'Reuse Recorded Resolution' capability of Git. You need to enable it. It will remember each of your 'fixes', and then if it needs doing again, it can reuse it. So you can practice the fixes, forget the bad ones, and re-run the rebase (use the --onto option for the temporary attempts).

The rerere documentation isn't great but there are a few web articles.

Comment: got it for the most part - so what is the purpose of git rebase if not for vanity?

Comment: @rakim Lets start at the other end, Git is a way that YOU get to version log YOUR software, warts and all, without any management restrictions. When you want to present your best work, you 'tidy up' all that dross, select the best bits (using rebase interactive to tweak), and then present a x10 dev's beautiful history. Or you just forgot which branch you were supposed to build on ;-). It's not vanity, it's being a professional (TM) (when time is available). But mainly use it/git to record YOUR work to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase` is about keeping a clean history on **top** of master. A lot of projects e.g. linux kernel, work in topic branches where each area/topic/driver is in it's own branch on top of master before it gets merged into master.

In most cases, we don't care about the multiple iterations that a developer went through before submitting a patch series. e.g. we don't need to know what parent commit the development was started on top of, how many times master was merged back into the branch, what fixes were made to the original commits, etc. In Mathematics terms, we want a clean final solution, not all the approaches you took to getting to that final solution.

All we want is a clean set of commits on top of master. `git rebase` is essential for that. It always keeps your changes on **top** of master, not as a confusing series of merges and fixes. This means, that during a rebase, you have to fixup each commit as it gets applied on top of master (that has moved forward) as if the commit was just produced on top of this version of master.

IOW, some projects prefer topic branches that are essentially private to the developer to be rebased, but master branch which is public always uses merge.

Comment: Just to say, that one can rebase a side thread/branch as it gets reviewed and polished. The 'top of master' is a local code choice. The other reason (for a rebase) can be that there was a bad mistake that should not be released beyond your local repo (the think before you push consideration)

Comment: Agreed, that is the main use of rebase in my case - as it gets reviewed and polished in successive versions of a kernel feature. I have noticed though that merge is so prevalent in most other projects and rebase is maligned to the point that it is never used. Like your comment in reply to OPs.